# How can i make native module use flutter string resource?

Tags: android, string, flutter, localization, native

There is a Flutter Project with another flutter module as its library. So i want to know if there is a way to help me to use the flutter String resource (path:/lib/l10n/xxx) for android native layout(xml) in the library module? I'll be glad to hear you. thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please be specific.

Comment: I need to custom the camera feature, so i add zxing library as my project's library, and its android native xml have string resource.  i want manage the string in main project instead of  in  the library.

Comment: Please provide the source code and explain clearly where your problem is. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.